# The execution is not at AddressOfEntryPoint after patching .text section bytes

Tags: windows, access-violation, portable-executable, shellcode

i have a shellcode and i want to inject my shellcode into a PE file (a simple compiled c program that prints Hello World on the screen) .
My shellcode size is 0x2a1 and the .text section of my pe file has enough space to hold it .
So i opened my PE file in PE-Bear and find the .text section RawOffset in file.
[image: .text section RawOffset in PE-Bear]
then i patch .text section bytes using HxD .
I set AddressOfEntryPoint in OptionalHeader to start of .text section where my shellcode is:
[image: AddressOfEntryPoint in PE-Bear]

So now  execution must be started from my shellcode bytes . but i ran pe file and got error:
[image: ERROR]

> template72.exe has encountered problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.

I open PE file using OllyDbg and execution isn't at position that i expected.
[image: OllyDbg]
AddressOfEntryPoint was 1000. it's RVA so the execution must be started at `0x00401000` since the ImageBase is `0x00401000` (PE file is not dynamic base) but it isn't that and we got Access Violation.

I'm useing Windows XP .
What is going on? And why does this happen?

Comment: You may get better support at [reverseengineering.se] than here!

Comment: Also: This is a [TLS callback](https://unprotect.it/technique/tls-callback/) (see the comment on the right of 0x401580), which will execute **before the entry point**. Perhaps what you changed broke something in that callback.